# Access/Permissions error when user confirms e-mail

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a "Join Now" menu option on the unregistered user front end. When a new user selects that menu option, they're presented the registration form. On completion they get a notice that a confirmation e-mail has been sent to them.

All standard stuff.

So... the user goes to their e-mail inbox, finds the confirmation e-mail and clicks the link. They're brought back to the site and they are still under the "Join Now" menu option...

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/join-now?view=login
```

So... the complete the login form, as expected. And there's the rub.

The 'Join Now' menu option is tied to the unregistered user permissions level and once they log in, it is no longer an active menu option. So, every time a new user logs in, they get an error message at the top of the page in the "drawer" box.

```
Error
You are not authorised to view this resource.
```

How do I fix that so that when they log in they get redirected back to the 'Home' menu and we don't get this error message? For the life of me I can't seem to figure that out, and I know it should be simple.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Both the login menu type and the login module have options that let you specify a redirect.

Comment: @ betweenbrain - Joomla 3.2

Comment: @ elin - but it's not a login menu item, it's a registration menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this inside your template:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$user = JFactory::getUser(); 
//redirect user if logged in
if ($user->id > 0) $app->redirect('index.php/menuwhereyouwanthimtogo');
```

Comment: This would work, I suppose, though I would be loath hack the template since a template patch/upgrade would break it. I'll give it a go as a module and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Making me crazy... I have been messing with getting an editor not to convert &, < and > to an HTML entities for hours now. /sigh I have tried them all, JRE, JCK, etc. JCK seems to be working best, but every time I save the module the > gets converted to &gt; and for the life of my I can't figure out where to turn that off.

Comment: @KScottPiel If you want to add HTML source code in TinyMce click `Tools`. Other editors have similar buttons for source code you could also check their settings. Editors however won't render php. You could try instead a [blank module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules) containing the above code or this [custom php plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470)

Comment: @ilas - JCK with the PHPCode plugin will allow you to write/edit/view PHP in your articles/modules using the <source> mode. The problem is that something in Joomla is converting < and > to &lt; and &gt; when I save the article/module - maybe this is better left as a separate Joomla question.

Comment: For the record, I did not edit the template to do this... rather, I created a "Custom HTML" module and placed this as a <?php ?> block in the module's HTML source and then just enabled it for the 'Join Now' menu option. Works like a champ once you get over the hump of getting PHP working in article content and does not cause issues if/when you upgrade your template.