# We have joomla site, a specific URL goes to login page when session is not active and does not get redirect after successful login

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

We have Joomla bases site - a given url to particular page works fine when user is logged in.

If user is not logged in, the url redirects to login page and stays there.

How to redirect the browser to load the intended page after login??

Comment: When the user is redirected to the login page is the referring url in the address bar?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912897/access-permissions-error-when-user-confirms-e-mail/20923810#20923810)

Comment: Are you managing this entirely from the administration console or do you have custom written templates, components, and/or plugins to leverage?

Comment: It sounds like you are redirecting to the login page, which means that you've left the page you want to load.  Instead of redirecting to login you might want to conditionally load a login module and set the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

At the place where you create the url to do the redirect append the return parameter to it. Something along the lines should work:

```
$return = base64_encode(JURI::getInstance(
              JFactory::getURI()->toString(array('path', 'query', 'fragment'))
          ));
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(
    JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=' . $return, true, true)
);
```